# Python: unwanted unicode type

Tags: python, unicode

I've got unicode strings (from an API query) that should have been encoded as regular ascii strings (as they already contain unicode representations). How can I change the encoding without actually changing the the characters being encoded?

To wit:

```
string = '165\xc2\xba F' # What I want
print(string)

my_string = u'165\xc2\xba F' # What I have
print(my_string)
```

PS I realize `\xc2\xba` is actually for ordinal number and not the degree sign (`\xc2\xb0`) but that's what I got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is not "unicode" is the byte sequence for the UTF-8 encoding of the string you want.

You can retrieve the text by using the "latin-1" codec to transparently transport your byte sequence to a byte-string (from your unicode-string) and
them, decode it normally from UTF-8:

```
In[]: u'165\xc2\xba F'.encode("latin1").decode("utf-8")
Out[]: u'165º F'
```

Why the latin-1 codec is special and works in this case is described on the second paragraph from here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#encodings-and-unicode

When you've got some minutes to spare it would be useful to read [this nice article on Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) to know what are codecs, and what does text in unicode mean.

Comment: `u'165\xba F'` is the output I got for your input. Only when I print that do I have the desired output. It's all very confusing.

Comment: Maybe I'm not using the right term, but doesn't the `u` necessarily designate my string as "unicode". I mean, that's what `type(my_string)` says.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I found that `my_string.encode('latin1')` will give me what I want. Much appreciated!

Comment: You really  should have your program deal with text as unicode instead.

Comment: The fact I had th 'right output' is that I've run the snippet in a Python3 console. Python3 uses Unicode by default, and outputs common printable characters as themselves, not an escaped representation.   To have the same output in Python2, use `print`.

Comment: @bongbang Alternatively you could say that `u` designates your string as *text*, rather than a chunk of *binary data*.